# FireDAC is locked in Delphi 11 professional?

Tags: delphi-11-alexandria

I am using Delphi 11 professional licnesed version.

In my data explorer, the FireDAC is locked, as below:

[image]

I check the editions in website and professional should include the support to FireDAC.